# What's a word for someone who's surpassed the teacher or master?

Tags: single-word-requests

So the context is this: I taught my friend how to play a video game and he's gotten to a point where he's passed all of my stats and records. I'm looking for a word to use like ronin (samurai without a lord or master) and I'm curious as to if that exists. Thank you ahead of time

Comment: I think that the two concepts (student that surpasses the teacher and masterless ronin) are not related, so your question is not clear.

Comment: The best teachers expect or at least hope to be surpassed by their students.